# Using operator to add 1 in while loop

Tags: php, mysqli, operators

I'm having trouble with the output in my statement.  I'm trying to add 1 to every instance of a username that is in the dB.  I have the following code:

```
$username = strtolower($fname . "_" . $lname);

$check_username_query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?");
$check_username_query->bind_param('s', $username);
$check_username_query->execute();

$result = $check_username_query->get_result();
$num_rows = $result->num_rows;  //count number of rows in the result

$i = 0;

//if username exists add number to username
while ($num_rows != 0) {

    $i++; //Add 1 to i
    $username = $username . "_" . $i;

    $check_username_query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?");
    $check_username_query->bind_param('s', $username);
    $check_username_query->execute();

    $result = $check_username_query->get_result();
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
}
```

This works fine for the first two:  ex.  `$fname` is John and `$lname` is Smith.  I get `$username` as `john_smith`.  For the next one I get `john_smith_1`  BUT, for the next one I get `john_smith_1_2`  and the one after I get `john_smith_1_2_3` and so on.  What I'd like for the third instance (& beyond) is  `john_smith_3` , `john_smith_4` etc.

Shouldn't the `$i` in `$username = $username . "_" . $i;` just continue to increment?

Comment: You should not overwrite your original username. So instead use something like: `$actualUsername = $username . "_" . $i;` and initialize it before the `while` like `$actualUsername = $username;`

Comment: `for the third instance`? So `john_smith_1_2` is the proper behavior? I would have thought `john_smith_2` would be expected.

Comment: it's what the code is outputting, but the behavior I'm looking for is `john_smith_3`

Comment: On the second iteration you want `john_smith_2` or `john_smith_1_2`?

Comment: By the way, you should avoid duplicating your code. Putting the sql check in a function would help with that.

Comment: the problem with `$actualUsername` is if `$num_rows` evaluates to `0` the username will end up being `$username` & the `while` loop will not be engaged.  My query is looking for `$username` to add to the dB.

Comment: surely the initial query ( if you are trying to determine if the username has already been used ) would be to use a `like` operator in the query ~ ` where username like "john_smith%"` etc ??

Comment: this code established the username.  My query adds allot to the dB and binds as follows `$query->bind_param('issssssisisiiisssssssssissssi', $empty, $fname, $lname, $username, $em, $hash, $date, $empty, $empty, $empty, $profile_pic, $zero, $zero, $zero, $no, $comma, $empty, $empty, $empty, $empty, $empty, $show, $empty, $empty, $empty, $banner_pic, $banner_pic_two, $token, $two);`  I'd rather not stick a `LIKE` in there if it can be resolved beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
$username = strtolower($fname . "_" . $lname);

$check_username_query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?");
$check_username_query->bind_param('s', $username);
$check_username_query->execute();

$result = $check_username_query->get_result();
$num_rows = $result->num_rows;  //count number of rows in the result

$new_username = 1;

$i = 0;
//if username exists add number to username
while ($num_rows != 0) {

    $i++; //Add 1 to i
    $new_username = $username . "_" . $i;

    $check_username_query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?");
    $check_username_query->bind_param('s', $new_username);
    $check_username_query->execute();

    $result = $check_username_query->get_result();
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

}

    if($new_username == 1){
      $username = $username;
    } else {
      $username = $new_username;
    }
```

Needed to assign `$new_username` as..something (I chose 1) then place it in the conditional at the end if `$num_rows == 0` and the `while` loop was not engaged.  Works as needed.  Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 2):

Use this piece of code:

```
$username = strtolower($fname . "_" . $lname);

$check_username_query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?");
$check_username_query->bind_param('s', $username);
$check_username_query->execute();

$result = $check_username_query->get_result();
$num_rows = $result->num_rows;  //count number of rows in the result

$i = 0;

//if username exists add number to username
while ($num_rows != 0) {

    $i++; //Add 1 to i
    $new_username = $username . "_" . $i;

    $check_username_query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?");
    $check_username_query->bind_param('s', $new_username );
    $check_username_query->execute();

    $result = $check_username_query->get_result();
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
}
```

Comment: My insert query after this is looking for `$username`.  If `$num_rows` evaluates to 0 and the `while` loop is not engaged, I will have a query trying to insert `$new_username`, when `$username` is what has been returned.